# Flex 4 focus multiple UIComponents

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, focusmanager

I'm currently coding a Floorplan editor with Flex 4.

I have a Floorplan Grid that extends the spark Group class.  This Floorplan Grid will contain objects that extend the UIComponent class.  I want the user to be able to select multiple objects on the Floorplan and be able for moving and resizing.

I'm just wondering if it's possible to have multiple objects being "focused" using the FocusManager, kind of like selecting multiple objects in Photoshop/Illustrator.

Comment: Why do you want to use FocusManager for this? I think it would be easier just to maintain an Array of selected items and apply changes to all elements in that Array.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have misunderstanding of what "Focus" is.  Only one object can have focus at a time.  Your mouse cursor can only click on one object and you can only send keyboard input to a single text box.

I can't, for example, type inside this browser textbox on stackoverflow and in the Microsoft Word document I have open at the same time.

It sounds to me like you want something like a List with [allowMultipleSelection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html#allowMultipleSelection) set to true, possibly using a [TileLayout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/layouts/TileLayout.html).   Or, if you feel that you need to write your own component, you'll have to implement your own rendition of 'allowMultipleSelection'.